# Trying to get Month to date sales value for each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Shipdate and Totaldue column in my salesOrderheader table.

My current query is like this

```
 select 
     [ShipDate], SUM([TotalDue]) Total 
 from 
     Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
 where 
     [ShipDate] between '2005-08-1' and '2005-08-31'
 group by 
     [ShipDate]
```

This returns the result for total sales for each day, I want a result where each date column corresponds to a value which shows month to date sale (i.e. totaldue here). Like if total due for 2005-08-1 is $1000 ,total due for 2005-08-2 is $3000 and total due for 2005-08-3 is $6000 then result should be,

```
ShipDate     MTD Value
-----------------------
2005-08-1     1000
2005-08-2     4000
2005-08-3    11000
```

And so on till 2008-08-31. I am kind of new to database and can't seem to figure this out. If anybody has idea how do to it, please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: is this adventureworks 2012 ?

Comment: Yes, I have a real time situation but I am trying it out in adventureworks2012 for testing.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want the sales for each MONTH instead of each DATE ? What is this monthToDate ?

Comment: Actually there are several sales each day, I want the total sales in day level. Now month to date is a value which shows total sale till that perticular date in a month. So each month to date for a day will show (that day's total sale + previous Month to date sale) I hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select soh1.ShipDate, SUM(soh2.TotalDue) from 
   (select distinct ShipDate from sales.SalesOrderHeader
        where ShipDate < '2005-09-01' and ShipDate >= '2005-08-01') as soh1
   join sales.SalesOrderHeader soh2 
        on soh2.ShipDate <= soh1.ShipDate and soh2.ShipDate >= '2005-08-01' 
   group by soh1.ShipDate order by soh1.ShipDate
```

The join will create the following resultset:

- ShipDate MTD Value
- 2005-08-1 1000
- 2005-08-2 1000
- 2005-08-2 4000
- 2005-08-3 1000
- 2005-08-3 4000
- 2005-08-3 11000

and the Sum and Group By joins the dates togheter.

Comment: Thanks, I guess It seems to be working. It will take a while for me to understand it. But If I may ask, I never saw <= operator being used in join condition before and also Subquery gives a date as a result so can we consider it as a table for joining SalesOrderHeader table. Thank you again for your help. :)

Comment: You can join on whatever column or value you want on a table. It does not have to be a foreign key. The subquery creates a resultset that you can do additional queries on and even join with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

This works and performs reasonably well:

```
;with soh as (
    select ShipDate, sum(TotalDue) as TotalDue
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    where ShipDate between '20050801' and '20050831'
    group by ShipDate
) 
select ShipDate, sum(TotalDue) over(order by ShipDate) as Total
from soh
```